# Aurelia Http fetch returns cached data

Tags: javascript, web, asp.net-web-api, aurelia

So I am new to Aurelia and web development in general.

Currently I have a view with a table of data.  After editing an entry and returning to the table I call my function to make another API call but instead my browser returns a 304 not modified (though in the database the values have been updated).

When I enable "always refresh from server" in Edge I get the results as I would expect.  Is there some way of telling this Http request to always call the API and not from the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could alter the url you're hitting to have some junk at the end of it.

```
this.http.get(url + "?_t=" + new Date().getTime(), data).done(function(values) {
  //do stuff
});
```

Not pretty, but it should work.

Similarly, you could construct your own call to use.

```
nonCachedGet(url, data) {
  return this.http.createRequest(url)
                  .asGet()
                  .withContent(data)
                  .withParams({ _t: new Date().getTime() })
                  .send();
}
```

It doesn't look like there are any specific settings telling the built in request methods not to cache, though.

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick.  So I am basically tricking the browser into thinking I'm sending a completely new request with each execution of the function?

Comment: Yeah, that's the short of it.

Comment: Is it fetch specific or browser specific behavior?

Comment: @MateuszJamiołkowski not sure what you mean by fetch specific, but it's definitely handled the same across browsers.

Comment: I do have the same problem using the "normal" HTTP client.